# How to sending CSRF token from SPA form

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, phpmailer

I made a simple form page in vue.js.
From there, I want to sent POST request with axios to PHPMailer located on another server.

So,how to make CSRF token in vue.js form?

I googled a lot,
but in many cases the form and phpMailer are on the same server and used SESSION.

What should I do in my case？

[image]

Comment: If server B requires a CSRF token, server A will need to get that token from server B when rendering its form, then submit it along with the other form data

Comment: Well, that means making a GET request before the POST request to get the token.  
   Thank you

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how your Vue app is structured you could either add the `CSRF-token` to the cookies, or to your store after authentication is successful. To achive CSRF protection, set it in the request headers for all state changing requests methods made by your frontend application.

```
fetch("/someurl", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": getCookie("csrf_access_token"),
    },
    credentials: "same-origin",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
```

It needs to be validated by the backend before whatever function is executed.

Comment: Thank you.
That means making a GET request before the POST request to get the Cookie.
But I have a question, why use Cookie?
Is it okay with Session?

Comment: You dont really need to make a request to get data from the cookies since it is accessible (except for http only) by the client. You could also save it in your store or wherever else. It depends very much on your usecase and app structure.

Comment: I understood why I use cookies. thank you very much